# How to combine these lines into one command in R

Tags: r

I want to run these as one line and combine them.

```r
df.lami$outcome.back <- df.lami$outcome.back %>% 
  replace(between(df.lami$outcome.back,3,10),"much improved")

df.lami$outcome.back <- df.lami$outcome.back %>% 
  replace(between(df.lami$outcome.back,2,2.9),"improved")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have 8598 observations  > range(df$outcome) [1] -9 to 10. I am trying to label less than -3 as "much worse", -2 to -2.9 as "worse", -1.9 to 1.9 as "same", 2 to 2.9 as "improved" and >3 as "much improved". When I run each line individually it changes numerical to character and then some data gets missed on the later lines. I figured if I run the lines as one command it would convert them all while still numerical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `cut` for this. Also it is easier to help when you provide  a small example of your data.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2.9, 3.2, 8.9, 5))
df$b <- cut(df$a, c(2, 3, 10), c('improved', 'much improved'))
df

#    a             b
#1 2.9      improved
#2 3.2 much improved
#3 8.9 much improved
#4 5.0 much improved
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `dplyr::case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df.lami %>%
  mutate(outcome.back = case_when(
    3 <= outcome.back& outcome.back <= 10 ~ "much improved",
    2 <= outcome.back& outcome.back <= 2.9 ~ "improved",
    T ~ NA_character_ # up to you
  ))
```